How to transmit videos directly from the website to RTMP server instead of using OBS?
I had a server to receive a specific RTMP video like RTMP: //domain.com/show and use OBS to record videos, what I have to do to be able to record videos on my own website and transmit it. . Access RTMP server instead of using OBS or any code can do that, thank you
I hope to be able to record videos directly on my website and play it back at the viewer page, like a livestream.

Browsers don't speak RTMP, so what you're asking for is impossible without some intermediary proxy.  What you can do though is ditch RTMP and use some other protocol.  In fact, you can use regular HTTP and the Fetch API for this, but that does require a server to support it.
